# Positioning 2 Elements Side by Side - On level with the left hand element static & right hand element width expanding with page

Tags: css, html, positioning

Ok I am desperately trying to position 2 elements, an aside & a section (I think the use of these HTML5 elements are relevant for what they hold).

For the following page [Click Here](http://www.russfrancis.co.uk/asia.htm) I am trying to get the 'Locations' (Aside) element to be static and stay on the left hand side of the container div. As for the 'Regions' (Section) I would like to have it stay on the right hand side of the page (on level with the 'locations' element) but when reduced in size I need it stay on the right and just reduce in width, with the contents inside displaying how I have it now. I seem to have set it up correctly in where the divs contained within it are displaying when reduced but am unable to position it next (On Level) to the locations element.

Please see the following markup:

```
<div class="mainwrapper">
  <aside id="locations">
    <h4 style="border-bottom: 1px dotted #990000;">Locations</h4>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="recentwork.htm">
          <span>Recent Work</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="asia.htm">
          <span>Asia</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="australia.htm">
          <span>Australia</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="britisles.htm">
          <span>British Isles</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="europe.htm">
          <span>Europe</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="london.htm">
          <span>London</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="morocco.htm">
          <span>Morocco</span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </aside>
  <section id="regions">
    <h4 style="text-align:left;">Asia</h4>
    <div class="thumbcontainer">
      <div class="thumb">
        <a href="india.htm">
          <img src="images/photo/tn/india.jpg" alt="India" width="310" height="207">
        </a>
        <h3>India</h3>
        <p>Country Description</p>
      </div>
      <div class="thumb">
        <a href="indonesia.htm">
          <img src="images/photo/tn/indonesia.jpg" alt="Indonesia" width="310" height="207">
        </a>
        <h3>Indonesia</h3>
        <p>Country Description</p>
      </div>
      <div class="thumb">
        <a href="malaysia.htm">
          <img src="images/photo/tn/malaysia.jpg" alt="Malaysia" width="310" height="207">
        </a>
        <h3>Malaysia</h3>
        <p>Country Description</p>
      </div>
      <div class="thumb">
        <a href="singapore.htm">
          <img src="images/photo/tn/singapore.jpg" alt="Singapore" width="310" height="207">
        </a>
        <h3>Singapore</h3>
        <p>Country Description</p>
      </div>
      <div class="thumb">
        <a href="thailand.htm">
          <img src="images/photo/tn/thailand.jpg" alt="Singapore" width="310" height="207">
        </a>
        <h3>Thailand</h3>
        <p>Country Description</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.mainwrapper {
width: 90%;
margin: 130px auto 0;
text-align:center;
}

.mainwrapper h4 {
text-align:center;
padding-bottom: 5px;
color: #FFF;
border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(153,0,0,1);
font-size:16px;
font-weight:200;
letter-spacing: 2px;
text-transform:uppercase;
font-family:'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif;
}

#locations {
background-color:rgba(26,26,26,0.8);
display:inline-block;
text-align:left;
width: 150px;
height:auto;
margin-top: 5px;
padding: 0 10px 0;
}

#locations ul {
list-style: none;
padding:0;
}

#locations li {
}

#locations li a {
text-align:left;
color:#FFF;
font-family:"Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
font-size:12px;
font-weight:normal;
margin:0;
text-decoration:none;   
}



#regions {
background-color:rgba(26,26,26,0.8);
display:inline-block;
vertical-align:top;
width: 90%;
margin-left: 20px;
margin-top: 5px;
padding: 0 10px 0;
}

.thumbcontainer {
display:inline-block;
width:100%;
}

.thumb {
background-color:rgba(18,18,18,0.8);
border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,1);
margin:10px 2px;
display:inline-block;
vertical-align:top;
width: 310px;
height:270px;
}

.thumb h3 {
color: #FFF;
border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(153,0,0,1);
font-size:14px;
font-weight:200;
letter-spacing: 2px;
text-transform:uppercase;
font-family:'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif;
margin:0 8px 0;
}

.thumb p {
color:#FFF;
font-family:"Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
font-size:11px;
text-align:left;
padding-left:8px;

}

.thumb img {
border:0;
}
```

Please find the link again [Here](http://www.russfrancis.co.uk/asia.htm)

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: Will the locations element be beside the regions element, on the left?  I don't know what you mean.

Comment: Apologies, yes the location element on the left and the regions on the right

Comment: So you want to shrink the Regions in width, so that there is room for the Locations element?  Or only when the window is resized?

Comment: I want the locations & Regions side by side, the locations with its fixed width positioned on the left and the regions to stretch to whatever the page width is on the right. (So with a percentage I believe) Thanks!

Comment: Ah. So the resizing doesn't matter?

Comment: I basically want the regions to resize how it is at the moment on the link provided. But would like it positioned side by side with the locations element.

Comment: Answered.  Let me know if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17632/discussion-between-franciru-and-bozdoz)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ...

Remove position: fixed from HEADER, remove width: 90% from #regions and replace the .mainwrapper CSS declarations with this:

```
.mainwrapper {
    margin: 40px 2% 0;
    padding-left: 168px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Kevin, I have put them changes on and it looks like it has taken the locations out of the flow as it is now stuck to the far left edge? www.russfrancis.co.uk/asia

Comment: change position: fixed to position: absolute

Comment: Still doing the same thing, Locations is stuck to the left of the screen. Seems that it has fallen out of the mainwrapper as this is set to 90%?

Comment: I see what you're saying, I almost had it, but looks like you reverted?

Comment: Why do you have position: fixed on the header?

Comment: Was just messing with a few other settings, have put it back to your suggestion now.

Comment: Updated my answer. You can play with the percentage in the mainwrapper margin if you want more whitespace.

Comment: Regions is now positioned below locations.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17633/discussion-between-kevin-boucher-and-franciru)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `float:left` and `float:right` on your Locations and Regions elements respectively so that they are on the same level, as you say.

I would also use media queries to change the width of the Regions element, because at 90% it isn't always going to be able to have the Locations element on the left.  Personally I think you should get rid of the percentage width on the Regions element and set it conditionally with media queries.

More information on Media Queries: [here](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/).

For example, your Regions element needs to be about 636px wide to have two photos showing.  So you can have a media query to allow for that width, plus the width of your margins, padding, and the Locations element width, and you'd have something like this:

```
@media (min-width: 956px) { 
#regions {
width: 636px;
}
}
```

And it needs to be 956px wide to have three showing.  So you can have another media query below it like this:

```
@media (min-width:1276px) { 
#regions {
width: 956px;
}
}
```

You can include `max-width:955px` to account for everything.  You use media queries like this so that when the page is adjusted it will show as many photos as it can hold on one row, and also display the Locations element.

Check out the JSFiddle I made, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bozdoz/m3ChW/), as an example.  Might want to see the full screen version, [here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/bozdoz/m3ChW/show/), to see how it works when you change the width of the browser window.

Comment: Looks good and is getting there. Is there a way to get rid of the possibility of the regions slipping under the locations when reduced to certain sizes, as it is on my page now?

Comment: @franciru You have on your .mainwrapper a padding-left of 168px.  You have to add that to all of your min-widths.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help & time @bozdoz I went with the other suggestion as it fitted my needs better. The media queries look very useful though. Thanks again!